# Display images uploaded on amazon S3 with symfony2

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, gaufrette

Which is the best practice to show images from a remote amazon s3 repos on a symfony2 project?

I used  KnpGaufretteBundle to upload the images on Amazon.

Comment: Display them how? `<img src="AWS S3 Link" alt="some alt text" />`

Comment: Yes but I'd like to show all images in my awsS3 folder, like a photo gallery, without knowing the name of each image, could I use a function that return to my website all names in the folder that I specify?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you would want to use the AWS SDK for PHP and then you will be able to access all the files in a given S3 drirectory. Then pass those to twig so you can render them.

[S3 Usage Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html)

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

...

public function gallaryAction(){
    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => '<aws access key>',
        'secret' => '<aws secret key>'
    ));

   $images = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Marker' => 'folder1/gallary/',
        //I believe marker is what would be use to say only objects in this folder. Not 100% on that.
   ));

    return $this->render('twig_template_name.html.twig',array('images'=> $images));
}
```

Then you would just use the images in your twig file to create the s3 link.

Comment: Thank you!!and if i would to take only images in a specific folder on s3,wher i could specify the folder name?

Comment: What is the folder structure you are trying to pull from? IE: `BUCKET/Folder1/Folder2/Images`?

Comment: I believe Marker would be used for that. not 100% you may have to check to docs to be sure.